# Jupyter Notebook client-server infrastructure

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been trying to find information about how a Jupyter Notebook works, but to no avail.

It is not clear to me how the server (which is where I suppose python runs - in a cloud based version of Jupyter ) sends its output to the frontend. For example, what would be the step by step process when displaying the output of the following in a Jupyter Notebook (for the sake of the argument, let's assume we don't have python installed locally):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'a': np.arange(50),
        'c': np.random.randint(0, 50, 50),
        'd': np.random.randn(50)}
data['b'] = data['a'] + 10 * np.random.randn(50)
data['d'] = np.abs(data['d']) * 100

plt.scatter('a', 'b', c='c', s='d', data=data)
plt.xlabel('entry a')
plt.ylabel('entry b')
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: The actual python is run at the server end via a `kernel`.  All that's run as the client end is the display and input handling.  Overall I think this is too big/broad of a question for SO.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the reply ! I understand what you are saying , yet I still cannot see how matplotlib would work in such a case. What response does the server send  to the frontend ? Thanks !

Comment: Even without the notebook layer, matplotlib, the python layer, interacts with some sort of `backend` - qt, tk, etc. which actually renders the plot window.  Except for selecting the backend configuration, most us don't pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you connect to the server via HTTP. Your browser should have a way to show HTTP requests and responses (e.g. under "Developer tools" or something) so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What I don't get is how the server send the output to the frontend , and how the frontend deals with these graphs , dataframes etc.

Comment: I believe most the interaction is via JSON files, with javascript running at the browser end.